# Request URL Data:Image Issue

Tags: php, apache, cakephp

I have a CakePHP application running on my local machine. When I try to access the *index* action for a particular Controller the browser shows a 'No Data Received' error.

When I look at the Request URL in the browser dev-tools, I see that it's set to:

> Request URL:data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAEgAAABIAQMAAABvIyEEAAAABlBMVEUAAABTU1OoaSf/AAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAAENJREFUeF7tzbEJACEQRNGBLeAasBCza2lLEGx0CxFGG9hBMDDxRy/72O9FMnIFapGylsu1fgoBdkXfUHLrQgdfrlJN1BdYBjQQm3UAAAAASUVORK5CYII=

..when the actual request URL should be: `localhost/users`

This is only happening for the UsersController..

The weird thing is when I deploy to my Staging or Production server, it works correctly and the page loads without any issues.

Can anybody shed some light on this please..? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you add some code?

Comment: *The weird thing is when I deploy to my Staging or Production server, it works correctly and the page loads without any issues.*, then it works right? So why not just let it live there?

Comment: I can't be developing from my staging or production servers. I need it to work locally.

Comment: ..as in, on my dev machine

Comment: Rightyo, what you need to do is see if any paths are different between the two, namely those starting with `/`, local may be something like `/projectname/include/file.php` where production may very well be `/vaw/www/htdocs/projectname/include/file.php`, that's my idea for this (*keeping in mind you've given us very little information to go off*)